# CSS advanced shape (heart cut out of background)

Tags: css, shapes, css-shapes

Basically I want to create a shape in CSS only (so no images) that is the opposite of a heart shape. I don't know how to explain it properly so here is an image:

[image]

The blue is the background, as you can see, but the shape that I want to create is not a heart, it is the shape of the black rectangle.

If I would have the following shape (THE GRAY NOT THE BLACK)

[image]

I could duplicate it and then rotate it, that would give me the shape I am looking for.

Comment: What you need is a mask, but I don't believe you can mask using another element - it still needs to be an image.

Comment: @ChristianVarga I know, that is the Photoshop term however, it should be possible with css -> border radius etc.

Comment: Assuming you did it... what about IE8? Any browser where positioning is *slightly* off?

Comment: @Mooseman The application I am creating does not support those browsers, so I don't mind. Back to my question ...

Comment: @ChristianVarga - Theoretically, you could do a "gradient" background that doesn't actually grade, or some other background that generates an SVG, because they're actually background images. Additionally (and unfortunately), CSS masks are [only a Webkit thing](http://caniuse.com/#search=mask).

Comment: @onlineracoon not really. You could use border radius to make the heart itself, in fact that would be quite easy. But border radius doesn't work the other way around, you need to mask it. Shauna is on the money, I'd say using an SVG mask on your element would be the best option here.

Comment: @ChristianVarga I know it is possible to create it in CSS, I don't want to use images or SVG's or gradients or webkit CSS masks. It might be little advanced but it should be a math issue to create the shape am I right?

Comment: @onlineracoon I'm sorry, but it just isn't possible to create that shape with pure CSS alone. Math has nothing to do with it, you can't "draw" with css. You can with Canvas, but that sounds like another idea you'll shoot down.

Comment: @ChristianVarga You can even do shaders with css! Of course it is not so handy as canvas, when we talk about drawing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Heart shape cut out using box-shadow

### Let's create this — the blue is the background color of `<body>`

[image: Screenshot]

### The pieces

Feel free to skip directly to the complete demo at the bottom of this answer :)

#### 1 - The rounded corners

The rounded top left and top right corners are created with `box-shadow` on the two pseudo elements with `border-radius: 50%` — `.heart:before` and `.heart:after` — They form two crescent shapes that look like this:

[image: Crescent Shapes]

#### 2 - The angle

The angled shape is created by the `box-shadow` on `.heart`. Combined with the two circles, it looks like this:

[image: Angled Shape]

#### 3 - The filler

We now need to fill in the gaps. This is done by the pseudo elements of the `.box-shape` container — `.shape-box:before` and `.shape-box:after`. The excess is cut-off neatly with `overflow: hidden` on the `.shape-box`. Combined with our pieces above, they look like this:

[image: The filler]

### The Complete Example

Combine it all together and we get this nicely cut out heart shape. It is all contained in `.shape-box`.

```css
body {
  background: #00A2F6;
}
.shape-box {
  height: 504px;
  width: 504px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.shape-box:before,
.shape-box:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 120px;
  background: #2B2B2B;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: 190px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
}
.shape-box:after {
  width: 760px;
  height: 750px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 220px #2B2B2B;
  top: -150px;
  left: -130px;
  background: none;
}
.heart {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 357px;
  width: 356px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 50px #2B2B2B;
  position: absolute;
  left: 74px;
  top: 34px;
}
.heart:before,
.heart:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 151px;
  height: 151px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: -40px -15px 0 20px #2B2B2B;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 157px;
}
.heart:after {
  box-shadow: -15px -40px 0 21px #2B2B2B;
  left: 156px;
  top: 51px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape-box">
  <div class="heart"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: **Seriously improved** - Since this was accepted, I really needed to clean it up and offer a better explanation. Hope you like it @onlineracoon and future readers :)

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with a combination of svg gradients, multiple backgrounds, and a little creative tiling/placement. Sample CSS from my [working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BueHh/1/) (without vendor prefixes, i.e. `-webkit` and `-moz`):

```
height: 400px;
width: 400px;
background-image:
  radial-gradient(75% 85.5%, circle, transparent 25%, black 26%),
  radial-gradient(25% 85.5%, circle, transparent 25%, black 26%),
  linear-gradient(225deg, transparent 25%, black 25%),
  linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 25%, black 25%);
background-size: 200px 200px;
background-position: top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

This makes a heart-shaped cutout in the middle of a `400px` square element. It can be modified to fit whatever size element you want.

Update: [here’s a more complex fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/684vK/1/) that uses six gradients instead of four, but looks a bit nicer.

Comment: Quite impressive, this is definitely the closest you can get with CSS.  Worthy of a many upvotes!

Comment: I don't see a heart in the fiddle, not even when I prefix it all (which should be not required in chrome I believe) http://jsfiddle.net/BueHh/12/

Answer (score 1):

Based on the work that Mark Hubbart did I was able to push this to a slightly more advanced form in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vePjf/39/)

This is not 100% complete yet as it will need some media queries to work across more browsers but it does show the start of a much more flexible working for the same goal.

```
#backgrounder {
z-index: 2;
background-image: 
   radial-gradient(68% 100%, circle, transparent 48%, white 30%), 
   radial-gradient(32% 100%, circle, transparent 48%, white 30%), 
   radial-gradient(110% 1%, circle, transparent 65%, white 30%), 
   radial-gradient(-8.5% 1%, circle, transparent 65%, white 30%), 
   linear-gradient(220deg, transparent 41%, white 30%), 
   linear-gradient(139deg, transparent 41%, white 30%);


 background-image: 
    -webkit-radial-gradient(68% 100%, circle, transparent 48%, white 30%), 
    -webkit-radial-gradient(32% 100%, circle, transparent 48%, white 30%), 
    -webkit-radial-gradient(110% 1%, circle, transparent 65%, white 30%), 
    -webkit-radial-gradient(-8.5% 1%, circle, transparent 65%, white 30%), 
    linear-gradient(220deg, transparent 41%, white 30%), 
    linear-gradient(139deg, transparent 41%, white 30%);

 background-size: 51% 31%, 50% 31%, 51% 50%, 50% 50%, 51% 51%, 50% 51%;
 background-position: top left, top right, 0% 30%, 100% 30%, bottom left, bottom right;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```